# How to use one .htaccess for all subdirectories?

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have this structure

```
deny from <ip>
```

in folder `fo`.

When I run `index.php` which is in `fo/`, ie. `fo/index.php` and my IP is `<ip>` then I get access denied.

When I run `index2.php` which is in `fo/newfolder/`, ie. `fo/newfolder/index2.php` and my IP is `<ip>` then I do get access.

How to use one `.htaccess` for all subdirectories?

Comment: Do you have `.htaccess` in `fo/newfolder/` as well?

Answer (score 0):

Technically, when you use `Deny from <ip>`, that gets inherited from all of the subdirectories that don't have anything that overrides a parent directive. Not sure why that's happening. You could also try using some other module to deny access. Example:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} <ip>
RewriteRule ^ - [L,F]
```